# What did I do wrong on this inequality problem?

Tags: inequality

The problem is:

> If $b < a$, what is the range for $x$ if $ax+a < bx+b$?

Below is my work:

> $$ax+a < bx + b$$
> $$(a+1)x < (b+1)x$$
> Divide both sides by $x$ and you get: $$a+1 < b+1$$
> Which can be simplified to $a<b$ if $x$ is positive.
> But $a<b$ contradicts to the statement given by the problem ($b<a$)

> Therefore $x$ is negative. The range for $x$ is $x<0$

However, the answer is *$x<-1$*. What did I do wrong?

Edit: Sorry everyone I made a typo on the original inequality.
The wrong simplification is what I did wrong.

Comment: $ax+a\ne (a+1)x$

Comment: $bx+a\neq (b+1)x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your initial algebra is in error: $ax+a$ equals $a(x+1)$, not $(a+1)x$, and $bx+a$ doesn’t simplify at all. What you should have done is subtract $a$ from both sides to get $ax<bx$. At this point I would rewrite it as $ax-bx<0$ and factor out the $x$ to get $(a-b)x<0$. We know that $a>b$, so $a-b>0$, and the product $(a-b)x$ is negative if and only if $x$ is negative. Thus, the solution is $x<0$. (It is **not** $x<-1$ if you copied the original inequality correctly.)

But there is a major error after the original algebraic error. Suppose for a moment that you really were dealing with the inequality $(a+1)x<(b+1)x$. When you multiply or divide both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality reverses its direction. For instance, $2<3$, but $(-1)\cdot 2=-2>-3=(-1)\cdot3$. And here you actually have **three** cases:

- If $x>0$, then $a+1>b+1$, and you do indeed get a contradiction, so $x\not>0$.
- If $x=0$, you can’t divide by it at all, but in that case $(a+1)x=0=(b+1)x$, so $a=b$, and again you get a contradiction. Thus, $x\ne 0$.
- If $x<0$, dividing by $x$ reverses the inequality: $a+1\color{red}<b+1$, so $a<b$, which is fine.

Had your initial algebra been correct, you should have concluded that $x<0$, thereby getting the right answer for the wrong reason.

Comment: Probably the original inequality  was meant  to be $ax+a<bx+b$. This would lead to  $x<-1$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: Yes, I expect that you’re right.

Comment: So the original question might be wrong?

Comment: @Cyh1368: It seems likely: $ax+a<bx+b$ would match the $x<-1$ answer.